# Can I merge the tags, branches, and trunks of two distinct subversion projects under a new parent project?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I have a repository like this:

- Repository Root

  - Project A1

    - trunk

      - A1 stuff
    - tags
    - branches
  - Project A2

    - trunk

      - A2 stuff
    - tags
    - branches

I would like to merge these two projects under a single parent directory, preserving history, tags, and branches, while avoiding the presence of the trunk/tags/branches subdirectories under each project in a local checkout.  So the new layout would look like this:

- Repository Root

  - Project A-prime

    - trunk

      - Project A1

        - A1 stuff
      - Project A2

        - A2 stuff
    - tags
    - branches

Is this even possible?  I'm dubious, since the tags are moving up one level relative to the files that they refer to.

I could merge just the trunks using only `svn move` commands (and the same for branches):

```
svn move /A1/trunk /A-prime/trunk/A1
svn move /A2/trunk /A-prime/trunk/A2
```

But this would not preserve the tags.  It seems like I might be able to create the new tag directories manually and move each subproject's tags over one at a time, but that seems ugly, and I'm not sure I can just move tags so easily - does Subversion give them special treatment somehow?

Answer (score 1):

When I understood your question right, you have one repository with the usual multi-project layout in it. You now want to restructure that one repository to a different layout.

That is of course possible. The reason for that is simple:

- Everything in tags and branches is just a (Subversion) copy of the trunk. A SVN copy is cheap, because it copies just the metadata. So e.g. a branch rel1 is a copy of the revision 4711 of your trunk. This structure will never change, so your branches and tags are valid.
- When you restructure your subversion repository by using only Subversion commands, Subversion ensures that you don't loose any information. You know for sure what your current content of your project "A1" is, and you know the history of all of that.
- You don't do real merging, you only move the content inside the repository.

The only thing that could break is when you are using `svn:externals` somewhere and these go to the current version (the head). You have to change all these definitions, because your structure has changed. And you have to know what to do, if some of the top-directories in the branches or tag directories (which were distinct previously) have the same name, so there is no distinction.

You could use a structure like that (similar to the trunk layout):

```
/tags
  /projectA1
    /rel1
    /rel2
  /projectA2
    /rel1
    /rel2
```

So go for it, and if something goes wrong, just recreate your repository from the dumped repository you have done beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can **try it with caution**. Some useful links for you (you forgot to do own homework)

- [How to Merge Two SVN Repositories](http://geekswithblogs.net/kariemali/archive/2009/06/02/how-to-merge-two-svn-repositories.aspx)
- [Merging SVN Repositories Explained](http://lizards.opensuse.org/2010/10/30/merging-svn-repos-explained/)
- [Merge SVN Repositories](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/svn-merge-repos.html)
- [Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)

**Hints**

SVN Book

> The dump format can also be used to merge the contents of several
>   different repositories into a single repository. By using the
>   --parent-dir option of svnadmin load, you can specify a new virtual root directory for the load process. That means if you have dump files
>   for three repositories—say calc-dumpfile, cal-dumpfile, and
>   ss-dumpfile—you can first create a new repository to hold them all:
>
> Then, make new directories in the repository that will encapsulate the
>   contents of each of the three previous repositories
>
> Lastly, load the individual dump files into their respective locations
>   in the new repository

Example from "Merge SVN Repositories"

```
svn-merge-repos.pl -t ./proj ./foo/trunk:proj1 ./bla/trunk:proj2
```

> Merge "trunk" of repositories "foo" and "bla" as subdirectories
>   "proj1" and "proj2" in repository "proj"

Comment: I did plenty of homework on this.  After a couple hours of googling and reading, including quite a few questions on stackoverflow, I decided that no one had done this particular thing and documented it, so I asked here.  I'm not merging two different repositories, so none of those links is exactly relevant (though there's plenty of useful information in them, thanks).